# How can I group by a string instead of ObjectId in MongoDB aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, collections, aggregate

I have two collections and a many-to-one relationship between them:

Product:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("61cc81c9585946c3b44f24411"),
        "name" : "some random name",
        "price" : 100,
        "description" : "description",
        "category_id" : ObjectId("61cc8100585946c3b44f2317d")
```

Category:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61cc8100585946c3b44f2317d"),
        "description" : "Category description",
        "name" : "Electronics"
}
```

I would like to output the maximum product price for each category:

```
db.product.aggregate([ 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$category_id",
        "max": { "$max": "$price"} 
    }}
])
```

This works just fine as it prints me the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61cc80fb585946c3b44f697c"), "max" : 62}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61cc8100585946c3b44f697d"), "max" : 100}
```

But is there a way to get the "name" from the Category instead of its object id?

I know in SQL you would group by category_name but it does not seem to work here.

Comment: You can use the `$lookup` for the "join" operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @prasad, you should make use of `$lookup` stage after your `$group` stage.

```
db.product.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$category_id",
      "max": {
        "$max": "$price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "categoryName",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "categoryName": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$categoryName.name",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kEEcKxlrwoy)